# Can i create function to change a specific CSS class with another class in wordpress?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

i got issue for updating new logo of twitter with the X new one ,
so i updated the font awesome package , but i wanna make a php function that can find the class of old icon " fa fa-twitter " to change with the new class of X "fa-brands fa-x-twitter"

Comment: If "*you wanna make [this] function,*" what's stopping you? How far did you get when you attempted to write this function? What went wrong, where did you get stuck?

Comment: function replace_css_class() {
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <style>
        .fa-brands.fa-x-twitter {
            /* Your new CSS styles for the replaced class */
        }
    </style>
    <?php
    $css = ob_get_clean();
    $css = str_replace('.fa.fa-twitter', '.fa-brands.fa-x-twitter', $css);
    echo $css;
}
add_action('wp_head', 'replace_css_class');
 
I already wrote it, but if someone can gimme another idea that makes it more efficient that will help more, so, u can help or na!

@DavidThomas

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using jQuery or js to do that.
For jQuery you can do something like:

```
$('.fa.fa-twitter').addClass('.fa-brands.fa-x-twitter').removeClass('.fa.fa-twitter');
```

For js you need to select all your instances (querySelectorAll or getElementsByClassName) then loop through them and use classList.add and classList.remove to manipulate the classes.

Answer (score 0):

just add this line to end of your fontawsome CSS file to show X logo as twitter old logo :

```
.fa-twitter:before{content:"\e61b"}
```